# Length and average height of Gerver's Sofa

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am currently investigating possible expansions and generalizations of the [moving sofa problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem). I am mainly considering higher dimensions and other angles. This led me to consider the height and length of both the Romik and Gerver sofas. Given the closed form of representation of the Romik sofa, I was able to easily calculate the average height from the length provided in his paper. However, the Gerver sofa can not be represented in closed form and I have been unable to find either its length or height in the literature. Is it a known result? If not, how could it be found?

Comment: Related, with references and images explaining what are the Gerver & Romik sofas: "[Sofa in a snaky 3D corridor](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246914/6094)."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thank you for pointing this out to me, it is a related result to what I am working on. I am looking at multiple versions of that sort of thing as well as 4(+)D versions and alternative angles.