# Balanced polygons

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Can someone explain to me what balanced polygons are and how they are used in calculations?

Particularly in Gerver's Sofa, Here is the link for the [research](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/data/uploads/papers/sofa.pdf), page 16

Thanks in regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> Gerver, Joseph L. "On moving a sofa around a corner." *Geometriae Dedicata* 42.3 (1992): 267-283.

Gerver says:

---

[image: Balanced]

---

As to "how they are used in calculations," I don't think there is a simple answer.
Gerver defined an infinite sequence of balanced polygons that converge to
what has now called Gerver's sofa (below).
I don't think balanced polygons play a role outside of Gerver's particular proof.

---

[image: Sofa]

---

Comment: Related: "[Sofa in a snaky 3D corridor](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246914/6094)."

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, and I've already seen your questions, it was fun to read.